# Is it proper to up vote both Question and Answer?

Tags: discussion, voting

Whenever I find an answer to a problem I have on Stack Overflow I tend to up vote the answer as well as the question. I figure give credit to the poster for asking the question in the first place.

Is this good practice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure.

If the question hadn't been asked, you'd have had to ask it yourself in order to get that answer you found helpful. So the question saved you work, demonstrating its usefulness.

Comment: I like this answer, I have found solutions to questions (even poorly written) because the user who answered it was able to still understand what the questioner was asking in the first place.

Comment: Don't hesitate to edit if you find yourself stumbling on the language in the question, @Cesar - even if the answerer was able to find the right interpretation, if it costs every reader some amount of time and frustration then it's worth fixing it.

Comment: I make edits all the time, I'm too anal :)

Answer (score 3):

If the question is actually *a good question*, then sure.  If it's a low quality question, or if you haven't looked closely at the question to evaluate it's quality, then you most certainly should *not* be upvoting it.